# Onion address encoding

Tags: ed25519, onion-routing

Could you please explain what the pipe (`|`) in [tor specification](https://github.com/torproject/torspec/blob/master/rend-spec-v3.txt#L2029) means -- is it a [bitwise or](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) or a concatenation of the values?

> 6. Encoding onion addresses [ONIONADDRESS]
>
>    The onion address of a hidden service includes its identity public
>      key, a    version field and a basic checksum. All this information is
>      then base32    encoded as shown below:
>
>    `onion_address = base32(PUBKEY | CHECKSUM | VERSION) + ".onion"`
>
>    `CHECKSUM = H(".onion checksum" | PUBKEY | VERSION)[:2]`
>
>    where:
>
>    - `PUBKEY` is the 32 bytes ed25519 master pubkey of the hidden service.
>    - `VERSION` is an one byte version field (default value `'\x03'`)
>    - `".onion checksum"` is a constant string
>    - `CHECKSUM` is truncated to two bytes before inserting it in `onion_address`

From the context, I understand it is a **concatenation**-- is that so?

If one has a working short Python\Node\Ruby snippet for that, it would be lovely.  :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to cryptography, but to the meaning of symbols in the technical specifications for a cryptographic tool.

Comment: Putting this on hold, Mr. The meaning of the symbol | depends on context, in this case Tor. Such questions are not related to cryptography but to the protocol in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspect, it's a concatenation symbol. Some times it's $|$ and others $||$.  Or $+$. [Python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python) and [PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm) examples to confirm. Or a cryptographic example: bottom of page 5 of [FIPS PUB 202: SHA-3 Standard: Permutation-Based Hash and
Extendable-Output Functions.](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf)

If it were bitwise OR, you'd make a real mess of the public key's use with `PUBKEY | CHECKSUM | VERSION`.

It can get weird though if you dig deeper as: [Is there a common symbol for concatenating two (finite) sequences?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/298648/394771)

Comment: thank you. have you got any example\tutorial on how to generate onion address v3 (hostname) on linux command line?

Comment: @Mr. Alas, no :-(